# Is $\varphi(B(x,r))$ a ball, $(U,\varphi)$ a chart in a smooth manifold $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connectedness

I'm reading a proof in which we take a chart $(U,\varphi)$ of a connected smooth manifold $M$, and consider $B = B(\varphi(x),r)$ a ball of center $\varphi(x)\in \varphi(U)$.

The part that I don't understand well is that they say directly that $\varphi^{-1}(B)$ is a ball. How can we assure it? In a more general way, can we say that images of homeomorphisms of balls are sent to balls?

The proof is from Theorem 10 of [this paper](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eglickenstein/math534_1011/Chap1.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is just a smooth manifold. Without any metric, it does not make sense to talk about balls in $M$.

However, it is **defined** in definition 5 of the linked notes that if $B \subset \varphi (U)$ is a ball in $\mathbb R^n$, then $\varphi^{-1}(B)$ is called a coordinates ball. In the proof of theorem 10, I don't see the author called $\varphi^{-1}(B)$ a ball. They do say that $(U, \varphi)$ is a coordinates ball, meaning that $\varphi(U)$ is a ball in $\mathbb R^n$.